# Terraform How To Interpolate Name Of Data Resource In Module Call

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

My goal is to call a policy module using a for_each such that for each policy name input, the correct policy_document is selected.  Is there a way to do this?  Example where the input is a map with a key `example-service`

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy-example-service" {
  statement {
    sid       = "AllowListBuckets"
    actions   = ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

module "policy_example" {
  source = "../modules/aws-iam-policy"

  for_each = var.example_policies_mapped_to_roles
  name        = "example-${each.key}"
  path        = "/"

  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy-${each.key}.json}" //so here "policy-example-service" would be filled in

}
```

This would allow me to have one module call defined with many different policy_documents.

Comment: It looks like this--`example_policies_mapped_to_roles = {
    example-service-policy = ["example-service-A"]
  }`. so the key in my idea for this would be `example-service-policy` and then in the end i'd have a bunch of other keys in the map

Comment: Oh whoops-- the comment I was responding to disappeared.  I'll leave that for clarification though.

Comment: The map idea works.  I think it's fine from an Admin perspective, but it's not very user friendly if the Admin is offering the module to a user.  "*note* Don't forget to add a new entry to the map for every policy you create" sort of README that ppl will forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you **can't do this**. TF does not support dynamically referencing resources in the form of `data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy-${each.key}.json`.

The way around this is to use `for_each` in your `aws_iam_policy_document.policy-example-service`

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy-example-service" {
 
  for_each = var.example_policies_mapped_to_roles

  # all this must be parameterized based on `each.key` values
  # for example with dynamic blocks
  statement {
    sid       = "AllowListBuckets"
    actions   = ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

Then, you could do:

```
policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy[each.key].json
```

The alternative is to keep your IAM policies in json files, and then load the files as needed.

Comment: Ahh ok that's disappointing.  I tried something like what you're showing there but the problem is I want to have many different policy documents with different permissions and in this case it will create identical policies for each entry in the map.  ie- the goal is each entry in the map would correspond to its own specific permissions (policy)

Comment: @Howard_Roark You can keep them in files, or variable map. You can also create a dedicated module for all these policies.

Comment: ok thanks for your ideas.  my team is big on the policy document strategy rather than json files so i'll think through your map or dedicated module idea